# Create multiple sharepoint list items based multiple uploaded files SP2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I would like to create sharepoint list items based on selected multiple files from local drive. After uploading selected multiple files list should contains new list items (title is file name) with attachments (one attachment/uploaded file).

Comment: Have you considered a document library instead? That is what they're for after all.

Comment: What is your question?  Are you just asking for us to give you the code to do all of this?  What have you done so far?  What are you having trouble doing?

Comment: Yes, I considered document library but there are some reasons to use list insead. Servy: I would like to use some built in forms (if possible multiple upload from document library). I done so far client side async tree view of list (with dynatree). Now I would like to create logic for uploading multiple files as list items? Thanks for downrating my question before my answer.

Comment: You could use the mult. upload for a document library, but not as attachments with one document per item.  Additionally one would assume that if you're attaching them to items that you also have other fields on the items to be populated based on the document, so in my experiences this always ends up being a custom (one time use) batch job.  You were downvoted because you didn't actually ask a question. It's not hard to write a job to do this, it's just tedious. It sounds like you're just expecting us to do that tedious work for you. If you wanted something else, you didn't ask it.

Comment: Servy I am not expecting source code from anyone. The answer should be: "No there is no way to use built in sharepoint forms or logic to add multiple list items from multiple uploaded forms".

Comment: You never asked a question.  Had you asked, "Is there a built in sharepoint tool that allows me to upload multiple documents as attachments to individual items" you would have gotten an answer. We cannot answer a question you haven't asked.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I extended my custom webpart (with dynatree) on that list using http://www.plupload.com/ and creating page for saving attachments.

```
public partial class ImportMultipleFilesAsListItems : LayoutsPageBase
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
//request form parameters comes from plupload
            int parentFolderKey = int.Parse(Request.Form["key"]);
            var file = Request.Files[0];

            SPList list = SPContext.Current.Web.GetList(Request.Form["listUrl"]);

            SPListItem folderItem = list.GetItemById(parentFolderKey);

            if (folderItem != null) 
            {
                string parentFolder = null;

                if (folderItem.Folder != null)
                {
                    parentFolder = folderItem.Folder.Url;
                }
                else
                {
                    int slashIndx = folderItem.Url.LastIndexOf('/');
                    parentFolder = folderItem.Url.Substring(0, slashIndx);
                }


                SPListItem childFile = list.AddItem(parentFolder, SPFileSystemObjectType.File);
                childFile["Title"] = file.FileName;
                childFile["IsFolder"] = 0;
                childFile["DocParentId"] = parentFolderKey;
                childFile.UpdateOverwriteVersion();

                byte[] data = new byte[file.ContentLength];

                file.InputStream.Read(data, 0, file.ContentLength);

                childFile.Attachments.AddNow(file.FileName, data);
            }

        }
    }

$(function () {
    var listInfo = new Object();
    listInfo.key = null;
    listInfo.listUrl = ctx.listUrlDir;
    listInfo.__REQUESTDIGEST = $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val();

    $("#uploader").pluploadQueue({
        // General settings
        runtimes: 'browserplus,html5,html4',
        url: $('#uploadMultipleFilesUrl').val(),
        max_file_size: '50mb',
        chunk_size: '1mb',
        multipart_params: listInfo,
        rename: true
    });
    // Client side form validation
    $('form').submit(function (e) {
        var uploader = $('#uploader').pluploadQueue();

        // Files in queue upload them first
        if (uploader.files.length > 0) {
            // When all files are uploaded submit form
            uploader.bind('StateChanged', function () {
                if (uploader.files.length === (uploader.total.uploaded + uploader.total.failed)) {
                    $('form')[0].submit();
                }
            });

            uploader.start();
        } else {
            alert('You must queue at least one file.');
        }

        return false;
    });

    $("#uploader").hide();
});
```